# iad won't move content to fit in (it covers the content)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, iad

I'm working on an app for both iphone/ipad all sizes. I've used the storyboard to place all the elements on screen: labels, buttons and images. Everything works perfectly. I want to place an iad at the bottom of the screen. So I places an iad from the object library and constrained it to the bottom of the screen, without constraining it to the other objects on the view. I've read that the iad has already the ability to push all content (resize) for it to fit on the screen. However when I run my app on the simulator, 6 out of 10 times the iad pushes the content up to make space for it to display. The other 4 times the iad covers the bottom label and button. It happens on all the simulator devices (5, 5s, 6, 6s, 6+ 6+s, ipad 2, ipad pro, ipad air, ipad air2, ipad retina.)

I'm using the following script to display the iad:

```
@IBOutlet weak var adBannerView: ADBannerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = true




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    self.adBannerView?.hidden = false



}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {

    return true

}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = true


}
```

Does anyone know or have an Idea on how to fix the problem I'm having?

Also in the apple manual it says that if iad fails to load it should be pushed offscreen. Do I need to write code to do this or will it do it automatically by its self?

[iad pushes content to fit in, screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISaJx.png)

[iad covers the content, screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gITQO.png)

Comment: You need to set constraints between the iAd view and your other elements.  If an ad isn't loaded it is up to you to remove the banner view; I suggest animating the view offscreen by changing the constraints

Comment: When I place a constraint on the iad and the button when iad appears it push everything up even higher. I get an unwanted empty space.

Comment: You need to make sure that the space in the constraint between the top of the banner view and the bottom of the button is what you want.  Also iAd is going away so you may not want to spend much time on it and investigate alternatives

Comment: Ok thanks, I didnt know that. So now that there wont be iad what should I use to win revenue from a free app??

Comment: Try AdMob as iAd alternative. iAd will get shut down.